# Getting SyntaxError from ArcPy Select by Layer?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.6

I am currently wondering what is the fastest way of using Select By Attributes in arcpy.
I have a GDB with a feature class that is quite big. This feature class has a field called CODE with values of type LONG.

I want to select 3 types of these features, namely the ones that have either 5020, 5601 or 8002 in the CODE field.

I tried running the following code:

```
SelectByAttribute=' "CODE" = ' 5020 ' OR "CODE" = ' 5601 ' OR "CODE" = ' 8002
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Bat_StudyArea", "NEW_Selection", SelectByAttribute)
```

I am getting a syntax error, but I am too blind to find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your quotation marks, also look at the ESRI [SQL reference page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm)

Try this:
`SelectByAttribute = """CODE = '5020' OR CODE = '5601' OR CODE = '8002'"""
 arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Bat_StudyArea", "NEW_Selection", SelectByAttribute)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `IN` in your SQL query, and don't include single quotes for numeric field values.

`CODE in (5020, 5601, 8002)`